# set Typeface font failed? what error is this?

Tags: java, android

What is causing my typeface error, I feel I am doing just like example I found.

```
public classGame extends AndroidGame {
static boolean FLAG_GAME_ACTIVITY = false;
static Typeface FONT;


public Screen getStartScreen() {
    AssetManager assetMgr = this.getAssets();
    Typeface FONT = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetMgr, "assets/font2.ttf");
    return new LoadingScreen(this);
}
```

the error:

```
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.em1soft.androidgames.jackheart/com.em1soft.androidgames.jackheart.JackHeartGame}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:265)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:239)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at com.em1soft.androidgames.jackheart.JackHeartGame.getStartScreen(JackHeartGame.java:19)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at com.em1soft.androidgames.framework.impl.AndroidGame.onCreate(AndroidGame.java:62)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
05-31 09:41:14.688: E/AndroidRuntime(4627):     ... 11 more
```

Later in my game I plan to call it with : (however, error raised before this)

```
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setTextSize(11);
    paint.setTypeface(JackHeartGame.FONT);
```

Comment: Is "assets/font2.ttf" spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't create another folder named `assets` inside the `assets` folder (like `assets/assets/font2.ttf`) which I believe you didn't, you just simply need to remove `assets` from the path.

```
Typeface FONT = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetMgr, "font2.ttf");
```

Follow this tutorial if you face any other problem [Android Using External Fonts](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/)

Comment: yes, this seems work, no error, but my font didn't change at all, i  also tried put some other fonts, change its name. where's the problem ?

Comment: @user3663196 you seems to load the font file as a local variable FONT but you used the static field FONT after which is null obviously and means you also need to delete "Typeface" from that line. `FONT = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetMgr, "font2.ttf");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setHVFont(Context context, TextView textView) {
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "hv.ttf"));
}
```